# General limit of a function with Pochhammer for any natural number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

The function

```
f[z_]:=2^(i-k/2-v/2) (k+v)! Gamma[1+i,z] Pochhammer[-v, i]/(i! k! Pochhammer[-k-v,i])
```

for $i,v,k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $z\in \mathbb{R}^-$ is for some combinations of $i,v,k$ only defined by the limit, e.g.

```
Limit[f[z], {i -> 2, v -> 1, k -> 0}]
(* Sqrt[2] Gamma[3, z] *)

f[z] /. {i -> 2, v -> 1, k -> 0}
(* Indeterminate *)
```

By using `Limit` I can only calculate the limit for special values. How can I get the expression of the general limit of $f$ for any $i,v,k \in \mathbb{N}_0$?

I do not want to treat the limit cases by `Piecewise`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function can also be written as `f1[z]*f2` where

```
f1[z_]:=2^(i-k/2-v/2)*(k+v)!*Gamma[1+i,z]/(i!*k!);
f2=Pochhammer[-v,i]/Pochhammer[-k-v,i];
```

In fact

```
f[z]-f1[z]*f2//Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

The function `f1` is regular. The factor `f2` can alternatively be defined as

```
f2alternative=Pochhammer[i-k-v,k]/Pochhammer[-k-v,k];
```

In fact

```
f2-f2alternative//FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

The main point is that `f2alternative` is regular, which is easy to see using

```
With[{max=3},Table[f2alternative,{i,0,max},{k,0,max},{v,0,max}]]
```

Hence

```
falternative[z_]:=f1[z]*f2alternative
```

should answer OPs question. For example

```
falternative[z]/.{i->2,v->1,k->0}
(* Sqrt[2] Gamma[3,z] *)
```

Comment: It would be nice if `FullSimplify` could be used to find representations that are regular at certain specified points. For example, if say `FullSimplify[Pochhammer[-v,i]/Pochhammer[-k-v,i],RegularAt->{i->2,v->1,k->0}]` would return `Pochhammer[i-k-v,k]/Pochhammer[-k-v,k]`. Of course I do not know if this is plausible, but I would think that `FullSimplify` explores different equivalent expressions, and perhaps this could be used as a constraint. (Maybe a function doing this kind of thing exists already in Mathematica?)

Comment: Good idea. I posted it at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/273950/69288