# Make expression at certain points regular

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Is there a way to find representations that are regular at certain specified points? For example the following both equations are identical, but the first is not regular at point $\{i=2,v=1,k=0\}$, whereas the second expression is regular at this point.

```
Pochhammer[-v, i]/Pochhammer[-k - v, i] /. {i -> 2, v -> 1, k -> 0}
(* Indeterminate *)

Pochhammer[i - k - v, k]/Pochhammer[-k - v, k] /. {i -> 2,v -> 1,k -> 0}
(* 1 *)
```

If say `FullSimplify[Pochhammer[-v,i]/Pochhammer[-k-v,i],RegularAt->{i->2,v->1,k->0}]` would return `Pochhammer[i-k-v,k]/Pochhammer[-k-v,k]`. Of course I do not know if this is plausible, but I would think that `FullSimplify` explores different equivalent expressions, and perhaps this could be used as a constraint.

The question was motivated from this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273913/69288).

MMA 13

Comment: FullSimplify has interesting options: ComplexityFunction, ExcludedForms, TransformationFunctions. Maybe they can be used to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it can be achieved within Mathematica by some tricks. Here is a useful package to deal with `Gamma`-related functions:

[Olsson.wl : a Mathematica package for the computation of linear
transformations of multivariable hypergeometric functions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.01189.pdf)

```
Block[{Print},Needs["Olsson`"]];

expr={Pochhammer[-v,i]/Pochhammer[-k-v,i],Pochhammer[i-k-v,k]/Pochhammer[-k-v,k]};

PochhammerSimplify[{k},#,{"GammatoPochhammer","PositivePochhammer"}]&/@expr
Out[]/.{i->2,v->1,k->0}
```

with the desired outputs,

```
{Pochhammer[1-i+v,k]/Pochhammer[1+v,k],Pochhammer[1-i+v,k]/Pochhammer[1+v,k]}

{1,1}
```

The function `PochhammerSimplify` accepts arguments like `PochhammerSimplify[index_List,exp_,actions_List]`, where the first one specifies the variables and the third one specifies some built-in rules.